# Get the ID of a new entry using Sequelize and SQLite without auto increment

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I want to use Node.js with Sequelize and SQLite. I have the following model for users:

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  rowid: {
    type: 'INTEGER',
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  // other properties
});
```

If I now execute `const newUser = await User.create({ /* properties */ })`, I would expect to be able to access the ID of the new user with `newUser.rowid`. But this is not the case, only if I add `autoIncrement: true` to the specification. Following https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html, I don't want to do this. Are there any other possibilities?

### Edit

As it turns out, this is only possible by creating the table without `autoIncrement: true` and only afterward add it to the column definition. The much more practical way is probably to just use autoincrement, the performance decrease won't matter for most small applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have to use `autoincrement` to access `rowid` in the table `User`. I would expect to see it this way `User.rowid` not `newUser.rowid` as in the example, since the table name is (apparently) `User`.

Also from the sqlite doc:

> if a rowid table has a primary key that consists of a single column
>   and the declared type of that column is "INTEGER" in any mixture of
>   upper and lower case, then the column becomes an alias for the rowid.
>   Such a column is usually referred to as an "integer primary key". A
>   PRIMARY KEY column only becomes an integer primary key if the declared
>   type name is exactly "INTEGER".

And finally, you might consider a different name than `rowid` for the PK, since sqlite already has a `rowid`.

> Except for WITHOUT ROWID tables, all rows within SQLite tables have a
>   64-bit signed integer key that uniquely identifies the row within its
>   table. This integer is usually called the "rowid". The rowid value can
>   be accessed using one of the special case-independent names "rowid",
>   "oid", or "*rowid*" in place of a column name. If a table contains a
>   user defined column named "rowid", "oid" or "*rowid*", then that name
>   always refers the explicitly declared column and cannot be used to
>   retrieve the integer rowid value.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The question was not about accessing the `rowid` in general, but accessing it directly after creating a new user, without reloading it using something like `find`. As it turns out, this is not possible, because Sequelize only replaces the primary key with the `lastInsertId` if `autoIncrement`  is set.

Comment: @FelixSchütz where did you get this "because Sequelize only replaces the primary key with the lastInsertId if autoIncrement is set." I check their document and I can't find it. I am facing the same question I raised here.

Comment: @Qiulang I just tried the following:
1. Create a table from a schema without auto increment. The schema stored in the database has no auto increment set and the primary key is not set after creating the entry.
2. Create a table from a schema without auto increment, then enable auto increment afterwards. The schema stored in the database has no auto increment set but the primary key is set after creating the entry.
3. Create a table from a schema with auto increment. The schema stored in the database has auto increment set and the primary key is set after creating the entry.